# URL Routing doesn't work when I don't include a parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So am trying to do some Routing and I seem to have an issue when I don't include any parameters. I am not sure if this is because I am linking from the master page or what.

Here is what is in my Global.asax App_Start Method

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Ninja", "SalesRep", "~/SalesRep/SalesRepHome.aspx");
```

My link from my master page is

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlFashion" runat="server" CssClass="navSubFont" Width="100%"    NavigateUrl="~/SalesRep" Text="Test">
```

When I run it like this, it just gives the 403.14 directory not found error.
However if I add a parameter on it seems to work fine

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlFashion" runat="server" CssClass="navSubFont" Width="100%"    NavigateUrl="~/SalesRep/TestParam" Text="Test">
```

Does anyone know why it wouldn't work without a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

SO the issue was, the directory was the same name as the route URL so I renamed the route URL to Rep and it works fine.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Ninja", "Rep", "~/SalesRep/SalesRepHome.aspx");
```